# Usage of ObservableField<String> over String in Android Databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, two-way-binding

I am new to Android Databinding and have got one doubt on the usage of ObservableField. 
Suppose,

```
private ObservableField<String> name; 

private String name;
```

In both cases, we have to call notifyPropertyChanged() while setting the new value. So, is there advantage of ObservableField over String?

Comment: No you don't need to call it when using observableField

Comment: You don't have to explicitly call your notify function in case you use ObservableField. You can simply listen to changes to it.

Comment: @ Muhannad, @ Ananth, Thanks for the clarification. I was creating new ObservableField object in the setter method, which breaks the logic. Now solved.

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableField` or `LiveData` is important concept of MVVM.

In your xml, you can define Observable data for xml. This data is always observed by xml. That means, if you set data to your name class, xml will be updated automatically.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="name"
        type="your.class.name"/>
</data>
```

And, use it in xml. For example, use name for `TextView`.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={name}"/>
```

Next, in your java code, insert your `ObservableField` name to binding.

```
YourBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this), R.layout.your, null, false);
binding.setName(name);
```